# Local image still needs explicit sizes set in Next.js

Tags: next.js

Reading their docs, I understood that using a local image (i.e.: from the `public/` folder) does not require explicitly stating the width and height for an image. This is how my setup looks like:

```
import Image from 'next/Image'

...

<Image src='/foo.jpg'/>
```

However, I am still getting this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Image with src "/foo.jpg" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property
```

`foo.jpg` exists in this location, along side numerous other assets that must be rendered in the same way. Would appreciate any pointers as to why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [import the image](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images) if you want `next/image` to automatically define the `height` and `width` props.

```js
import Image from 'next/Image'
import foo from '../public/foo.jpg'; // imported images don't have to be in the public directory

<Image src={foo} />
```

*Note - require and dynamic import is not supported*

If you're in a bind and must dynamically select the images you can technically do the following

```js
import Image from 'next/Image';
import img0 from 'your/src/path';
import img1 from 'your/src/path';
import img2 from 'your/src/path';

const imagesObject = { img0, img1, img2 };

<Image src={imagesObject['img0']} />

{Object.entries(imagesObject ).map((_, k) => (
 <Image src={imagesObject[`img${k}`]} />
))}


const imagesArray = [img0, img1, img2];

<Image src={imagesArray[0]} />

{imagesArray.map((_, k) => (
 <Image src={imagesArray[k]} />
))}
```

Comment: Ah, I imagined using a local `src` would do the same. That being said, I cannot really import these images, given their dynamic nature. Does this mean I cannot take advantage of the framework's image size detection?

Comment: @linkyndy That's right. If you can't import the images statically (as mentioned above), then Next.js can't analyse the images at build time to determine their width/height.

Comment: Technically you can import all of the images on one page and assign them to an object key or array.  Then dynamically select the correct one from the loop or whatever you're doing.  I updated the answer to reflect this option.